# Can a map be added to a .ics file?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

When setting the location of an event in Calendar on a Mac it offers suggestions which when clicked embeds a map into the event. Is it possible to embed a map into a `.ics` file so that the map shows once imported? It seems that simply setting `LOCATION` when creating the calendar file isn't sufficient.

I've scanned [RFC 2445](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt) but can't find anything to help.

My assumption is that to embed a map into the event the user needs to specifically select a location from the suggestions offered when typing and that this can't be done automatically on import. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Can you export an `.ics` from an event with an attached map? I think iCalendar stores the map information internally and you can't import or export it through `.ics`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***short-answer:*** NO you cannot embed a map in the .ics file, but your calendar render could do it by parsing .ics file

***long-answer:***

`RFC2445` was supersed by `RFC5545`

`RFC5545` specifies in section [8.3.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-8.3.4), the following data types of which none allow you to have a map in an .ics file:

```
     +-----------------+---------+--------------------------+
     | Value Data Type | Status  | Reference                |
     +-----------------+---------+--------------------------+
     | BINARY          | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.1  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | BOOLEAN         | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.2  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | CAL-ADDRESS     | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.3  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | DATE            | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.4  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | DATE-TIME       | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.5  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | DURATION        | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.6  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | FLOAT           | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.7  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | INTEGER         | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.8  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | PERIOD          | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.9  |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | RECUR           | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.10 |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | TEXT            | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.11 |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | TIME            | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.12 |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | URI             | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.13 |
     |                 |         |                          |
     | UTC-OFFSET      | Current | RFC 5545, Section 3.3.14 |
     +-----------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

To achieve what you want to do, your calendar renderer needs to parse either the calendar property `LOCATION` (see [3.8.1.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.7)) which is a string, or better if you have it you could parse the property`GEO` (see [3.8.1.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.6) ) which is two floats giving longitude and latitude.

Comment: Best answer on the planet!